# nomenclature references to wrong page

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am adding acronyms and using the nomenclature package, it is somehow however on click referencing to the list of tables page instead of the nomenclature page. What is the problem?

I am also getting the error (Option clash for package nomencl.)

I tried removing the second package which might be a duplicate, the same problem occurs, any fix?

Thanks!

I am using in my preamble:

````
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[stdsubgroups,nocfg]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature```
````

Comment: You definitely shouldn't have both of those `\usepackage` commands, though it's probably the first you want to get rid of. If that's not the problem (it probably isn't.) then you need to provide a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). We can't diagnose the problem with so little information.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill try to provide a mwe.